# printing multiple values from a key in a dictionary with user input

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is my dictionary that has multiple values assigned to one key

```
courseinfo = {'CS101': [3004, 'Haynes', '8:00 AM'],
            'CS102': [4501, 'Alvarado', '9:00 AM'],
            'CS103': [6755, 'Rich', '10:00 AM'],
            'NT110': [1244, 'Burke', '11:00 AM'],
            'CM241': [1411, 'Lee', '1:00 PM']
                }
```

I need to make it so that when the user enters a course name, it prints all 3 values.

For example, if the user says CS101, then it should print [3004, 'Haynes', '8:00 AM']

I've tried a few different ways, but none of them seem to work:

```
x = input("enter course name:")
for key, value in courseinfo.items():
    if x == key:
        print(key)
```

```
key = input("enter course name:")
if key in courseinfo:
    print(courseinfo[key])
```

```
x = input('enter course name:')
for i in x:
    print(courseinfo[i])
```

Comment: Try to go through this link and see if it helps. The answer from @vjsr should help you but it does not provide enough documentation on why. This link should help you get a better understanding of why. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45072283/how-to-use-a-python-dictionary Also see https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp

Answer (score 2):

Just get the value in the dictionary by the key:

```
courseinfo = {'CS101': [3004, 'Haynes', '8:00 AM'],
            'CS102': [4501, 'Alvarado', '9:00 AM'],
            'CS103': [6755, 'Rich', '10:00 AM'],
            'NT110': [1244, 'Burke', '11:00 AM'],
            'CM241': [1411, 'Lee', '1:00 PM']
                }
                
                
            
x = input("enter course name:")
print(courseinfo[x])
```